# how can i set time zone as UTC + 08:00 programmatically

Tags: php, timezone

How can i change site time zone programmatically in php by selecting time zone from dropdown in settings page?

I have following value in dropdown:

```
UTC - 05:00 
UTC - 04:30 
UTC - 04:00 
UTC - 03:30 
UTC + 08:00 
UTC + 09:00 
UTC + 10:00
```

Comment: not sure about your use case with the drop down, but I would look into moment.js

Comment: All such dropdowns are inherently flawed.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date_default_timezone_set("timezone")`

It accepts one of the following strings as a timezone:

```
"America/Adak",
"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
"America/Argentina/La_Rioja",
"America/Argentina/San_Luis",
"America/Atikokan",
"America/Belem",
"America/Boise",
"America/Caracas",
"America/Chihuahua",
"America/Cuiaba",
"America/Denver",
"America/El_Salvador",
"America/Godthab",
"America/Guatemala",
"America/Hermosillo",
"America/Indiana/Tell_City",
"America/Inuvik",
"America/Kentucky/Louisville",
"America/Lima",
"America/Managua",
"America/Mazatlan",
"America/Mexico_City",
"America/Montreal",
"America/Nome",
"America/Ojinaga",
"America/Port-au-Prince",
"America/Rainy_River",
"America/Rio_Branco",
"America/Santo_Domingo",
"America/St_Barthelemy",
"America/St_Vincent",
"America/Tijuana",
"America/Whitehorse",
"America/Anchorage",
"America/Argentina/Catamarca",
"America/Argentina/Mendoza",
"America/Argentina/Tucuman",
"America/Atka",
"America/Belize",
"America/Buenos_Aires",
"America/Catamarca",
"America/Coral_Harbour",
"America/Curacao",
"America/Detroit",
"America/Ensenada",
"America/Goose_Bay",
"America/Guayaquil",
"America/Indiana/Indianapolis",
"America/Indiana/Vevay",
"America/Iqaluit",
"America/Kentucky/Monticello",
"America/Los_Angeles",
"America/Manaus",
"America/Mendoza",
"America/Miquelon",
"America/Montserrat",
"America/Noronha",
"America/Panama",
"America/Port_of_Spain",
"America/Rankin_Inlet",
"America/Rosario",
"America/Sao_Paulo",
"America/St_Johns",
"America/Swift_Current",
"America/Toronto",
"America/Winnipeg",
"America/Anguilla",
"America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia",
"America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos",
"America/Argentina/Ushuaia",
"America/Bahia",
"America/Blanc-Sablon",
"America/Cambridge_Bay",
"America/Cayenne",
"America/Cordoba",
"America/Danmarkshavn",
"America/Dominica",
"America/Fort_Wayne",
"America/Grand_Turk",
"America/Guyana",
"America/Indiana/Knox",
"America/Indiana/Vincennes",
"America/Jamaica",
"America/Knox_IN",
"America/Louisville",
"America/Marigot",
"America/Menominee",
"America/Moncton",
"America/Nassau",
"America/North_Dakota/Beulah",
"America/Pangnirtung",
"America/Porto_Acre",
"America/Recife",
"America/Santa_Isabel",
"America/Scoresbysund",
"America/St_Kitts",
"America/Tegucigalpa",
"America/Tortola",
"America/Yakutat",
"America/Antigua",
"America/Argentina/Cordoba",
"America/Argentina/Salta",
"America/Aruba",
"America/Bahia_Banderas",
"America/Boa_Vista",
"America/Campo_Grande",
"America/Cayman",
"America/Costa_Rica",
"America/Dawson",
"America/Edmonton",
"America/Fortaleza",
"America/Grenada",
"America/Halifax",
"America/Indiana/Marengo",
"America/Indiana/Winamac",
"America/Jujuy",
"America/Kralendijk",
"America/Lower_Princes",
"America/Martinique",
"America/Merida",
"America/Monterrey",
"America/New_York",
"America/North_Dakota/Center",
"America/Paramaribo",
"America/Porto_Velho",
"America/Regina",
"America/Santarem",
"America/Shiprock",
"America/St_Lucia",
"America/Thule",
"America/Vancouver",
"America/Yellowknife",
"America/Araguaina",
"America/Argentina/Jujuy",
"America/Argentina/San_Juan",
"America/Asuncion",
"America/Barbados",
"America/Bogota",
"America/Cancun",
"America/Chicago",
"America/Creston",
"America/Dawson_Creek",
"America/Eirunepe",
"America/Glace_Bay",
"America/Guadeloupe",
"America/Havana",
"America/Indiana/Petersburg",
"America/Indianapolis",
"America/Juneau",
"America/La_Paz",
"America/Maceio",
"America/Matamoros",
"America/Metlakatla",
"America/Montevideo",
"America/Nipigon",
"America/North_Dakota/New_Salem",
"America/Phoenix",
"America/Puerto_Rico",
"America/Resolute",
"America/Santiago",
"America/Sitka",
"America/St_Thomas",
"America/Thunder_Bay",
"America/Virgin",
"Indian/Antananarivo",
"Indian/Kerguelen",
"Indian/Reunion",
"Australia/ACT",
"Australia/Currie",
"Australia/Lindeman",
"Australia/Perth",
"Australia/Victoria",
"Europe/Amsterdam",
"Europe/Berlin",
"Europe/Chisinau",
"Europe/Helsinki",
"Europe/Kiev",
"Europe/Madrid",
"Europe/Moscow",
"Europe/Prague",
"Europe/Sarajevo",
"Europe/Tallinn",
"Europe/Vatican",
"Europe/Zagreb",
"Pacific/Apia",
"Pacific/Efate",
"Pacific/Galapagos",
"Pacific/Johnston",
"Pacific/Marquesas",
"Pacific/Noumea",
"Pacific/Ponape",
"Pacific/Tahiti",
"Pacific/Wallis",
"Indian/Chagos",
"Indian/Mahe",
"Australia/Adelaide",
"Australia/Darwin",
"Australia/Lord_Howe",
"Australia/Queensland",
"Australia/West",
"Europe/Andorra",
"Europe/Bratislava",
"Europe/Copenhagen",
"Europe/Isle_of_Man",
"Europe/Lisbon",
"Europe/Malta",
"Europe/Nicosia",
"Europe/Riga",
"Europe/Simferopol",
"Europe/Tirane",
"Europe/Vienna",
"Europe/Zaporozhye",
"Pacific/Auckland",
"Pacific/Enderbury",
"Pacific/Gambier",
"Pacific/Kiritimati",
"Pacific/Midway",
"Pacific/Pago_Pago",
"Pacific/Port_Moresby",
"Pacific/Tarawa",
"Pacific/Yap",
"Africa/Abidjan",
"Africa/Asmera",
"Africa/Blantyre",
"Africa/Ceuta",
"Africa/Douala",
"Africa/Johannesburg",
"Africa/Kinshasa",
"Africa/Lubumbashi",
"Africa/Mbabane",
"Africa/Niamey",
"Africa/Timbuktu",
"Africa/Accra",
"Africa/Bamako",
"Africa/Brazzaville",
"Africa/Conakry",
"Africa/El_Aaiun",
"Africa/Juba",
"Africa/Lagos",
"Africa/Lusaka",
"Africa/Mogadishu",
"Africa/Nouakchott",
"Africa/Tripoli",
"Africa/Addis_Ababa",
"Africa/Bangui",
"Africa/Bujumbura",
"Africa/Dakar",
"Africa/Freetown",
"Africa/Kampala",
"Africa/Libreville",
"Africa/Malabo",
"Africa/Monrovia",
"Africa/Ouagadougou",
"Africa/Tunis",
"Africa/Algiers",
"Africa/Banjul",
"Africa/Cairo",
"Africa/Dar_es_Salaam",
"Africa/Gaborone",
"Africa/Khartoum",
"Africa/Lome",
"Africa/Maputo",
"Africa/Nairobi",
"Africa/Porto-Novo",
"Africa/Windhoek",
"Africa/Asmara",
"Africa/Bissau",
"Africa/Casablanca",
"Africa/Djibouti",
"Africa/Harare",
"Africa/Kigali",
"Africa/Luanda",
"Africa/Maseru",
"Africa/Ndjamena",
"Africa/Sao_Tome",
"Atlantic/Azores",
"Atlantic/Faroe",
"Atlantic/St_Helena",
"Atlantic/Bermuda",
"Atlantic/Jan_Mayen",
"Atlantic/Stanley",
"Atlantic/Canary",
"Atlantic/Madeira",
"Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
"Atlantic/Reykjavik",
"Atlantic/Faeroe",
"Atlantic/South_Georgia",
"Asia/Aden",
"Asia/Aqtobe",
"Asia/Baku",
"Asia/Calcutta",
"Asia/Dacca",
"Asia/Dushanbe",
"Asia/Hong_Kong",
"Asia/Jayapura",
"Asia/Kashgar",
"Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
"Asia/Magadan",
"Asia/Novokuznetsk",
"Asia/Pontianak",
"Asia/Riyadh",
"Asia/Shanghai",
"Asia/Tehran",
"Asia/Ujung_Pandang",
"Asia/Vladivostok",
"Asia/Almaty",
"Asia/Ashgabat",
"Asia/Bangkok",
"Asia/Choibalsan",
"Asia/Damascus",
"Asia/Gaza",
"Asia/Hovd",
"Asia/Jerusalem",
"Asia/Kathmandu",
"Asia/Kuching",
"Asia/Makassar",
"Asia/Novosibirsk",
"Asia/Pyongyang",
"Asia/Saigon",
"Asia/Singapore",
"Asia/Tel_Aviv",
"Asia/Ulaanbaatar",
"Asia/Yakutsk",
"Asia/Amman",
"Asia/Ashkhabad",
"Asia/Beirut",
"Asia/Chongqing",
"Asia/Dhaka",
"Asia/Harbin",
"Asia/Irkutsk",
"Asia/Kabul",
"Asia/Katmandu",
"Asia/Kuwait",
"Asia/Manila",
"Asia/Omsk",
"Asia/Qatar",
"Asia/Sakhalin",
"Asia/Taipei",
"Asia/Thimbu",
"Asia/Ulan_Bator",
"Asia/Yekaterinburg",
"Asia/Anadyr",
"Asia/Baghdad",
"Asia/Bishkek",
"Asia/Chungking",
"Asia/Dili",
"Asia/Hebron",
"Asia/Istanbul",
"Asia/Kamchatka",
"Asia/Kolkata",
"Asia/Macao",
"Asia/Muscat",
"Asia/Oral",
"Asia/Qyzylorda",
"Asia/Samarkand",
"Asia/Tashkent",
"Asia/Thimphu",
"Asia/Urumqi",
"Asia/Yerevan",
"Asia/Aqtau",
"Asia/Bahrain",
"Asia/Brunei",
"Asia/Colombo",
"Asia/Dubai",
"Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
"Asia/Jakarta",
"Asia/Karachi",
"Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
"Asia/Macau",
"Asia/Nicosia",
"Asia/Phnom_Penh",
"Asia/Rangoon",
"Asia/Seoul",
"Asia/Tbilisi",
"Asia/Tokyo",
"Asia/Vientiane",
"Australia/Canberra",
"Australia/LHI",
"Australia/NSW",
"Australia/Tasmania",
"Australia/Broken_Hill",
"Australia/Hobart",
"Australia/North",
"Australia/Sydney",
"Pacific/Chuuk",
"Pacific/Fiji",
"Pacific/Guam",
"Pacific/Kwajalein",
"Pacific/Niue",
"Pacific/Pitcairn",
"Pacific/Saipan",
"Pacific/Truk",
"Pacific/Chatham",
"Pacific/Fakaofo",
"Pacific/Guadalcanal",
"Pacific/Kosrae",
"Pacific/Nauru",
"Pacific/Palau",
"Pacific/Rarotonga",
"Pacific/Tongatapu",
"Pacific/Easter",
"Pacific/Funafuti",
"Pacific/Honolulu",
"Pacific/Majuro",
"Pacific/Norfolk",
"Pacific/Pohnpei",
"Pacific/Samoa",
"Pacific/Wake",
"Antarctica/Casey",
"Antarctica/McMurdo",
"Antarctica/Vostok",
"Antarctica/Davis",
"Antarctica/Palmer",
"Antarctica/DumontDUrville",
"Antarctica/Rothera",
"Antarctica/Macquarie",
"Antarctica/South_Pole",
"Antarctica/Mawson",
"Antarctica/Syowa",
"Arctic/Longyearbyen",
"Europe/Athens",
"Europe/Brussels",
"Europe/Dublin",
"Europe/Istanbul",
"Europe/Ljubljana",
"Europe/Mariehamn",
"Europe/Oslo",
"Europe/Rome",
"Europe/Skopje",
"Europe/Tiraspol",
"Europe/Vilnius",
"Europe/Zurich",
"Europe/Belfast",
"Europe/Bucharest",
"Europe/Gibraltar",
"Europe/Jersey",
"Europe/London",
"Europe/Minsk",
"Europe/Paris",
"Europe/Samara",
"Europe/Sofia",
"Europe/Uzhgorod",
"Europe/Volgograd",
"Europe/Belgrade",
"Europe/Budapest",
"Europe/Guernsey",
"Europe/Kaliningrad",
"Europe/Luxembourg",
"Europe/Monaco",
"Europe/Podgorica",
"Europe/San_Marino",
"Europe/Stockholm",
"Europe/Vaduz",
"Europe/Warsaw",
"Indian/Cocos",
"Indian/Mauritius",
"Indian/Christmas",
"Indian/Maldives",
"Indian/Comoro",
"Indian/Mayotte",
"Australia/Brisbane",
"Australia/Eucla",
"Australia/Melbourne",
"Australia/South",
"Australia/Yancowinna"
```

So you can set a value attribute of your dropdown list to the string from the list above and pass it to the `date_default_timezone_set` function.